# Unity 3D C# Check for Vector3 in List

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I'm using Argon Granberg's A* Pathfinding scripts and I'm trying to check if a list element is defined

There is a list of Vector3 values stored as p.vectorPath variable. I'm trying to test if list elements are defined with

```
if ( p.vectorPath[myIndex] != null ) {
...
```

But I'm getting the error in Unity that testing a Vector3 != null will always = true. So how can i test if this particular list index is defined?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "defined"? Do you mean initialized? Vector3 is a value type (struct) and there is no such thing as an undefined (or null) value type (except if you make it nullable). Value types are initialized in the moment they are declared in c# - if you didn't provide an initial value, it has its default value (Vector3.zero in this case)

Comment: Should've posted that as the answer

Comment: OTOH, if what you want is to know if the list has any element at the position N, you could just check if list.Count is greater than N

Comment: @C.Carter, I would, but i'm not sure if it's what OP means

Answer (score 2):

`Vector3` is a value type (`struct`) and there is no such thing as an undefined (or null) value type (except if you make it nullable). Value types are initialized in the moment they are declared in c# - if you didn't provide an initial value, it has its default value (`Vector3.zero` in this case)

OTOH, if what you want is to know if the list has any element at the position `N`, you could just check if `list.Count` is greater than `N`

Comment: @GeoffL so, did you apply this suggestion? Did this answer help you? If yes, you can mark this as "accepted", so it'll be easier for other people with the same issue to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As with the other answer `Vector3` cannot be null as it is a value type. You could declare the list with a `Nullable` type of `Vector3` like this;

```
public class Foo
{
    public List<Vector3?> VectorPath;
}

Foo p = new Foo();

//...stuff...

if (p.VectorPath[someIndex].HasValue)
{
    //Do things.
}
```